# Specify a blank value in a custom PickList field via api

Tags: bigcommerce

How can I specify an empty value for a custom-field 
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/customer-subscribers/v3-customers-api/customer-form-fields/customerformfieldvalueput

`PUT https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/:store_id/v3/customers/form-field-values`

```
[
    {
        "name": "MyCustomField",
        "address_id": 395,
        "value": ""
    }
]
```

gives me this

```
{
    "status": 422,
    "title": "Create form field value failed.",
    "type": "https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/api-status-codes",
    "errors": {
        "0.form_field_value": "Option '' does not exist in 'MyCustomField'"
    }
}
```

I have also tried
`"value": null` 
with result

```
"errors": {
    "0.data": "Missing form-field value for form-field 'MyCustomField'"
}
```

`"value": undefined`
with result

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "title": "Input is invalid",
    "type": "https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/api-status-codes",
    "errors": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the custom form field doesn't already exist on the store you're sending this call to, you'll see an error like "Form-field 'test' does not exist in the 'Customer' form". Once set to an existing field's name, I was able to successfully send a call like the one described here.

Are you also creating the custom form field programmatically? You might need to add logic so that this call is only run after the field is created.

Comment: The custom form-field for the address definitely exists. 
> I was able to successfully send a call like the one described here.
that sounds amazing. Can you please supply the VERB, PATH and BODY for the call that will clear the value from a PICKLIST custom-field?

> Are you also creating the custom form field programmatically?
No. the Custom field was created in the Admin Console.